# Start function from a specific row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

I want to know, how can i run a method or a function or a loop for just the `not-NaN` rows. I don't want to dropna the dataframe and reset the index. For now, I am using the AvgHigh function but it's considering the `NaN` rows too. Also, if the suggested method can be used with series and arrays both. if not, please suggest for both. Thanks in advance.

## Edit

```
def AvgHigh(src, val) :
    dat_list = []
    last_src = np.nan              # init variable that keeps the prev iteration value
    for a in range(len(src)) :
        if src[a] > val :
            dat_list.append(src[a])    # yield src[a]
            last_src = src[a]          # update prev iteration value (for next iteration)
        elif (src[a] <= val) and (a == 0) :
            dat_list.append(np.nan)    # yield np.nan
        elif (src[a] <= val) and (a != 0) :
            dat_list.append(last_src)  # yield src[a-1]
    return dat_list

df1['high_r'] = AvgHigh(df1['Values'], 14020)
```

[image]

Comment: please show the example result you wanted

Comment: Sorry @nay , actually i realized rolling method is not the issue here, the AvgHigh function is what i want to start with non- NaN rows. Thanks for the update, I have updated the ques and the code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get the high_r column you are looking for. Added in a check on the pd.nan values.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'values': [np.nan, np.nan,np.nan, np.nan,np.nan, 14018,14022,14023,14021,14020,14014]})

def AvgHigh(src, val) :
    dat_list = []
    last_src = np.nan              # init variable that keeps the prev iteration value
    for a in range(len(src)):
        if not np.isnan(src[a]): ##<<<<<<New if statement
            if src[a] > val :
                dat_list.append(src[a])    # yield src[a]
                last_src = src[a]          # update prev iteration value (for next iteration)
            elif (src[a] <= val) and (a == 0) :
                dat_list.append(np.nan)    # yield np.nan
            elif (src[a] <= val) and (a != 0) :
                dat_list.append(last_src)  # yield src[a-1]
        else: ##<<<<<<New else statement
            dat_list.append(np.nan)
    return dat_list

df1['high_r'] = AvgHigh(df1['values'], 14020)
df1

     values   high_r
0       NaN      NaN
1       NaN      NaN
2       NaN      NaN
3       NaN      NaN
4       NaN      NaN
5   14018.0      NaN
6   14022.0  14022.0
7   14023.0  14023.0
8   14021.0  14021.0
9   14020.0  14021.0
10  14014.0  14021.0
```